# MVC SqlQuery of IdentityUser table with paging and where clause

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, claims-based-identity

I have would like to query the users of my web site... these are stored in the AspNetUsers table and have extra fields as defined in my OhansonsUser object, which inherits from IdentityUser as follows:

```
public class OhansonsUser : IdentityUser<long, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{ 
....
}
```

I am trying to make the following query:

```
        var sql = @"
SELECT  *
 FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Id ) AS RowNum, *
        FROM      AspNetUsers
        WHERE     Id > 2
      ) AS RowConstrainedResult
WHERE   RowNum >= 1
  AND RowNum < 20
ORDER BY RowNum
";
        var users = Global.OhansonsDbContext.Database.SqlQuery<IEnumerable<OhansonsUser>>(sql).ToList();
```

And I am getting the error: "The result type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[OhansonsLib.OhansonsUser]' may not be abstract and must include a default constructor."

Note: It does have a default constructor.

Comment: you try leaving off IEnumerable? `Database.SqlQuery<OhansonsUser>`

Comment: Yes this was the main problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the model type directly, not the type of collection you expect. It then tries to instantiate that type and execute the mapping based on that type. So the exception is generated because an interface is not a concrete type and could never be instantiated. If you look at the documentation it will return type `DbRawSqlQuery<TElement>` which itself implements `IEnumerable<TElement>`.

By the way you can also implement paging directly using Lambdas using `Skip` and `Take`. Example (assuming the DbSet on the DbContext is named `Users`).

```
int pageSize = 20, pageIndex = 0;
var users = OhansonsDbContext.Users.OrderBy(user => user.Id).Skip(pageSize * pageIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Comment: I added the where and the order by clauses:    
         Global.OhansonsDbContext.Users
                .Where(o => o.Id > 2)
                .OrderBy(o => o.Id)
                .Skip(pageSize * pageIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();

Comment: @BrianRice - Yes, the OrderBy is critical and I did not mention that (sorry) otherwise the default sort order is used in the database if I am not mistaken.